# ListBox Divider according to Item Property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a list of items of type `ViewLookupItem` which has these properties:

[image: Show Properties of LookupItems without Group]

For example this item example has no group, however an item can belong to a group, like the one below:

[image: Show Properties of LookupItems with Group]

What I want to do is, when an Item belongs to a group I want to show it under a divider and if the item does not belong to a group show it normally, this is my current `ListBox` below (the one on the left):

[image: listbox]

I want it to look something like this when the Items belong to a group:

[image: grouped list box]

I think I need to use some kind of triggers, but I don't know how to use them, any help would be much appreciated :) this is the current XAML of my `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="Black" 
         Height="303" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="15,59,0,0" 
         Name="lstResults" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="295" 
         SelectionMode="Multiple" 
         AllowDrop="True" 
         local:ListBoxSelector.Enabled="True"     
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lstResults_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
         PreviewMouseMove="lstResults_PreviewMouseMove" TabIndex="1" 
         PreviewMouseDoubleClick="lstResults_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       FontSize="14"/>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You could use a TreeView for such a behaviour... (though you could do it manually with a listbox, TreeViews were designed for this)

Comment: Can I apply a template to a listbox to look like a treeview? because for my functionality I need to use a listbox....

Comment: Sure... it's WPF :) You could use a DataTemplateSelector so that, according to the groupe, the ItemTemplate is different: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Comment: TreeViews are for hierarchical data. This data is not hierarchical - merely grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a collection view over your collection and tell it to group by your `Group` property. You can then define a `GroupStyle` on your `ListBox` to define how a grouping is visualized.

Here is a simple example (doesn't follow best practices or MVVM or anything, but serves to illustrate collection views for your scenario):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SO11343251
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly ICollection<ViewLookupItem> items;
        private readonly ICollectionView itemsView;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.items = new List<ViewLookupItem>();

            this.items.Add(new ViewLookupItem("Amenities", "No Group"));
            this.items.Add(new ViewLookupItem("Indoor", "Area"));
            this.items.Add(new ViewLookupItem("Outdoor", "Area"));

            this.itemsView = new ListCollectionView((IList)this.items);
            this.itemsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ICollection<ViewLookupItem> Items
        {
            get { return this.items; }
        }

        public ICollectionView ItemsView
        {
            get { return this.itemsView; }
        }
    }

    public class ViewLookupItem
    {
        private readonly string name;
        private readonly string group;

        public ViewLookupItem(string name, string group)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.group = group;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
        }

        public string Group
        {
            get { return this.group; }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="SO11343251.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="No Group">
                                <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**Result**:

[image]